# Define Multiple Enums in a Single File in Matlab

Tags: matlab, enums, matlab-class

Is it possible to define multiple enumerations in a single Matlab file? Or is it possible to have "local" enums in the same way we can define local funtions at the end of a file?

I am working on a project where it would be handy to have multiple enumeration classes, but it is annoying to use a `classdef` every time because it requires a separate file, and this means that there are lots of short files whose sole purpose it is to define enumerations. At the moment, each enumeration looks like this:

```
classdef exampleEnumType < uint32
    
    enumeration
        zero(0),
        one(1),
        two(2),
    end

end
```

Is there a way to compactly define enumerations in Matlab so that I do not need a separate file for each (using Matlab 2021a)?

Comment: What do you need these enigma for? MATLAB doesn’t do type checking, they’re just constants. You can define constants easily, just without them being an enum.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Its mainly for scripts which are used by a lot of users that have different possible settings. Storing the settings in an enum makes it easier to understand the code as you read it.

Comment: Maybe just some `categorical` variables would be a good approach here? For each different "enumeration" you want, stick a `categorical` array holding all the valid values for it in a `Constant` property all in one class. How exactly are these "enumerations" going to be used?

Comment: We need a full working example using categorical.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, having lots of short files is the normal situation in MATLAB. Working around that is possible but oftentimes futile.

Traditionally in MATLAB, constant values are defined as a function. For example, `pi` is a function. It looks something like this:

```matlab
function v = pi
   v = 3.14159
```

By making the constant into a function, it is available from everywhere without first running code to define those constants.

An enumeration is nothing more than a series of constants. The same can be accomplished with a struct:

```matlab
exampleEnumType = struct('zero',0, 'one',1, 'two',2);
```

Since fairly recently (R2019b), MATLAB allows [dot indexing into the output of a function call](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/indexing-into-function-call-results.html), but you do need to use empty parenthesis in the function call. Thus, we can declare the above struct the same way we did with constants:

```matlab
function v = exampleEnumType
   v = struct('zero',0, 'one',1, 'two',2);
```

This allows to do `exampleEnumType().zero` (almost) like with the enum or with a struct variable.

So how do we extend this to defining multiple of these in a single file? If a common prefix is no problem, we can define a class with static member functions, each one declaring a constant:

```matlab
classdef constants
   methods(Static)
       function v = pi
          v = 3.14159
       end
       function v = exampleEnumType
          v = struct('zero',0, 'one',1, 'two',2);
       end
   end
end
```

We now have `constants.pi` and `constants.exampleEnumType().zero`.

Alternatively, create a single function that returns a more complex struct as follows:

```matlab
function v = constants
   v.pi = 3.14159;
   v.exampleEnumType = struct('zero',0, 'one',1, 'two',2);
```

This allows us to do `constants().exampleEnumType.zero`.

Note that the above will not work in the same way for MATLAB releases prior to R2019b. For older versions of MATLAB, the last method (a function `constants`) would be the best approach. The user would just need to do `constants = constants;` at the top of any function needing to use the constants. This shadows the function with a variable of the same name, so that `constants.exampleEnumType.zero` works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and suggestion, one point is that `exampleEnumType.zero` will not work, but you need to call `exampleEnumType().zero` (see https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/indexing-into-function-call-results.html Supported Syntaxes under the first point)

Comment: After a bit more playing around, my point above only applies to standalone functions but not to methods of a class.

Comment: @fishlein Interesting, I hadn't noticed that caveat. Will update answer. It is unfortunate, because in general it is not necessary to use empty parenthesis to call a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map...

```
exampleEnum = containers.Map( {'zero','one','two'}, {0,1,2} );
```

usage looks like

```
exampleEnum('zero') % = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you might want to use `categorical` arrays here, and stick "enumerations" of their valid values as constants in a common class.

```matlab
classdef Constants

    properties (Constant)
        
        Foods = categorical(["apple", "banana", "pear"])

        SupportedProtocols = categorical("http", "https", "ftp")

        SpeedOfGravityMps = 9.86

    end

end
```

If you want them to be true Matlab `enumeration`s, then yeah, you're stuck with a separate file for each.

Comment: I tried this, but using it gives me the error "class definition uses an instance of itself directly or indirectly as the default value for the 'connection' property. This is
not allowed"

Comment: That error message sounds like you are using a user-defined class instead of the "just use categoricals" approach described in this answer, and that you are initializing a non-Constant property of that class using an instance of that class in a property default value. That won't work, due to the circularity. I don't think there's a way to really do that. To get close, make it a Constant property, or define the instance property without a type constraint and initialize it in the constructor, in an `init()` method, or lazily in a getter method.